# atio6axx.pdb not loaded during OpenGL debug

Tags: c++, debugging, opengl, fragment-shader, pdb-files

I'm writing OpenGL code for a project, using Visual Studio and C++. I have created a shader that contains a Uniform Block correctly linked and initialized in the source code. This is the source code part:

```
unsigned int sunLightUBO;
glGenBuffers(1, &sunLightUBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sunLightUBO);
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 48, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, 12, &sunDirection);
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 12, 12, &sunAmbient);
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 24, 12, &sunDiffuse);
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 36, 12, &sunSpecular);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
unsigned int sunLightIndex = glGetUniformBlockIndex(floor.ID, "sunLight");
glUniformBlockBinding(floor.ID, sunLightIndex, 0);
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, sunLightUBO);
```

While this is the part related to the shader, specifically the Fragment Shader:

```
layout (std140) uniform sunLight
{                       //offset
    vec3 direction;     //0
    vec3 ambient;       //12
    vec3 diffuse;       //24
    vec3 specular;      //36
};
```

When I try to compile it gives me this error:
[image: ERROR]

I've been trying to solve this problem for some time now. I tried to search all over the internet, looking for a solution, but even if they dealt with the problem of the .pdb file not loaded, they were not solutions that helped me.

I illustrate below everything I have tried:

1. I activated the two servers available by default (Microsoft Symbol Servers and NuGet.org Symbol Server) and I let all the modules load without making exceptions. I also tried to set "atio6axx.dll" as the only module to load.
2. Since I have an ATI Radeon video card, I added as server symbol, the one provided by AMD that is https://download.amd.com/dir/bin found on the site https://gpuopen.com/learn/amd-driver-symbol-server/. Even with this server added and activated, I tried to load all the modules and then only the one I needed (atio6axx.dll).
3. I downloaded PDB Downloader at the link https://github.com/rajkumar-rangaraj/PDB-Downloader/releases/download/v1.0/PDBDownloader.exe but it didn't help because it couldn't download the file I needed.
4. I manually copied the atio6axx.dll file to the same directory as the source code

If I try to remove the Uniform Block in the fragment shader, everything works fine, so surely it's because of it. I don't know what else to try, does anyone have a solution?

EDIT

I corrected the part about the offset and the memory allocated in the buffer:

```
unsigned int sunLightUBO;
glGenBuffers(1, &sunLightUBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sunLightUBO);
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 64, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, 16, &sunDirection);
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 16, 16, &sunAmbient);
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 32, 16, &sunDiffuse);
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 48, 16, &sunSpecular);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
unsigned int sunLightIndex = glGetUniformBlockIndex(floor.ID, "sunLight");
glUniformBlockBinding(floor.ID, sunLightIndex, 0);
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, sunLightUBO);
```

and

```
layout (std140) uniform sunLight
{                       //offset
    vec3 direction;     //0
    vec3 ambient;       //16
    vec3 diffuse;       //32
    vec3 specular;      //48
};
```

Unfortunately, the error persists and is always the same

EDIT 2

Using the "Step Over" debug option, I found that the exception is thrown upon arriving at the line where I create the unsigned int sunLightUBO:

```
unsigned int sunLightUBO; <--Here the exception is thrown
glGenBuffers(1, &sunLightUBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sunLightUBO);
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 48, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, 12, &sunDirection);
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 12, 12, &sunAmbient);
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 24, 12, &sunDiffuse);
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 36, 12, &sunSpecular);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
unsigned int sunLightIndex = glGetUniformBlockIndex(floor.ID, "sunLight");
glUniformBlockBinding(floor.ID, sunLightIndex, 0);
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, sunLightUBO);
```

Before this line I only create and link one shader. Before that, there are all the classic lines for initializing a window with GLFW and pointers to OpenGL functions with GLAD.
I also tried to initialize the variable that throws the exception, setting it equal to 0, but it doesn't change anything.

SOLUTION

After several attempts, I decided to test the project on another pc. I state that: the initial pc with which I encountered the error is an HP Pavilion dv6 6c80el which is equipped with an ATI Radeon HD 7690M XT video card and is almost 10 years old. The second pc on which I tested the project, on the other hand, is decidedly more powerful in everything and is equipped with a GTX 980.

While debugging on the second pc, I immediately noticed that the console was showing me errors in the fragment shader code, which the first pc did not show. The error was related to the syntax used inside the fragment shader main; to refer to the variables within the Uniform Block, I wrote (in my case) sunLight.direction (for example). Instead you had to write only direction. Unfortunately the console did not show me these errors in the first pc and consequently I did not insert the code regarding the main in the initial question, my mistake. In any case I don't know why the console didn't show me these errors. I think it's because my Radeon card worked differently in debugging than the NVidia GTX.

Correct the syntax, the console would start showing me errors again. Fixed these last errors, always related to the fragment shader (conversion problems from vec3 to vec4 ...), the program started correctly.

Also, to write shaders, I use a Visual Studio extension called "GLSL Language Integration". Apparently this extension fails to recognize all syntax errors of a GLSL code, because for example the fact that I wrote sunLight.direction instead of direction, did not report it to me. And as a result of this, the engine that handled syntax error checking was not working. For example, given a vec4 called vector, I could write vector.rgbdsfuiweda and it wouldn't report it to me as an error anyway.
In other words, the syntax error that he could not recognize, confused the recognition of many other possible errors in the code. So you have to be very careful.

Comment: Does AMD provide this file? Do you really need or want to debug your GPU drivers? A pdb not loaded does not affect execution of your program. It just prevents you from digging into the detail of the dll.

Comment: The page you link to states: *"Please note that we currently just host the binaries (in our case these are a set of DLLs), not the PDBs which is what you would need to resolve function names. There are currently no plans to release the PDBs."* It is very unlikely that you will be able to debug into the GPU driver.

Comment: I do now see that the AMD symbol server does not provide pdbs however I am somewhat confused at the purpose of the AMD symbol server in that case.

Comment: @drescherjm AMD does not provide this file. Apparently the absence of this file does not allow the correct execution. I don't understand what you mean by: debug your GPU drivers.

Comment: @BDL Yes, actually I had read that part, only having never had a problem like this, I really didn't know what to do. It is the first time I have encountered a problem with these .pdb files and I don't know how to handle them.

Comment: "atio6axx.pdb not loaded" isn't the error. The error is "exception thrown ... access violation reading ..." "atio6axx.pdb not loaded" is just visual studio telling you why it can't show you the code where the error happened

Comment: Btw, if you use linux, you can use the opensource driver stack for AMD, and can actually debug into mesa.  I sometimes even use mesa's sw renderer (when possible) to debug GL problems of an GL _application_, but it still is a lot of work and I only use it as a kind of last resort.

Comment: ***I don't understand what you mean by: debug your GPU drivers*** The purpose of this file is to see the internal implementation details of the GPU driver. If you wanted to understand what was going on inside the driver from a call of your program a pdb file would be essential.  You don't need or most likely don't want this to run or debug your code. The not loaded message is not causing any type of problem in your program and its not something you need to fix to continue working on your project.

Comment: The error looks like a null pointer dereference. Make sure the `this` pointer is not null and none of your pointers are null.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to debug into the AMD GL implementation isn't going to get you any insights. YOu should fix your GL code instead:

> ```
> glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 48, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
> ```

Nope, your buffer is too small, `std140`-layout specifies that `vec3` elements are aligned at 16 byte boundaries, so:

```
layout (std140) uniform sunLight
{                       //offset (yours)   CORRECT offset
    vec3 direction;     //0                0
    vec3 ambient;       //12               16 
    vec3 diffuse;       //24               32
    vec3 specular;      //36               48
};
```